# Games + Closed Lid = Hibernation

Tags: laptop, cooling, gaming

I have an ASUS N53S that I mainly bought for its RAM capacity. (I run a lot of VMs.) But as a bonus, it came with a fancy ATI video card. So I decided to install GTA 4 and plug it into a big monitor and settle down for some casual mayhem.  But after about 5 minutes, it goes into hibernation! What gives?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I was using an external monitor and didn't need the keyboard (using an XBox controller) I closed the lid on the laptop. Gaming is compute-intensive, so my GPU and CPU were both working hard and generating heat. Closing the lid interfered with cooling. Since I have the laptop configured to hibernate when I press the power button, the heat-triggered shutdown caused hibernation.

Comment: I'm not the downvote, but I'm skeptical of this answer.

Comment: Skepticism is good, as long as it's explained.

Comment: My guess is that the box doesn't recognize just running the external display, with top closed, as being "busy", so it does what it's been told to do.  (Hard to believe that the box is nice and cool with the lid open but overheats in only 5 minutes with it closed.)

Comment: There's no configuration that says "I'm idle when the lid is closed for 5 minutes". And even there were, it's obviously not set. I often work with the lid closed for hours at a time -- it's only graphics-intensive games that cause a shutdown.

Comment: I have to say it bugs me to be criticized and downvoted when nobody has an alternative explanation.